# Foundation: Scale columns of grid to full width

Tags: html, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

I have a row where i don't need the 12 columns of foundation grid. Is it possible to scale these columns to full width with a margin between columns calculated dynamically (not with class small/medium/large-offset) by foundation, so that it fit's to the screen size?

This is my coding, where columns are directly next to each other:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="large-2 medium-2 small-2 left white centered" >
      //Content
 </div>

 <div class="large-1 medium-1 small-1 left white centered" >
      //Content
 </div>
 <div class="large-2 medium-2 small-2 left white centered" >
      //content
 </div>
 <div class="large-1 medium-1 small-1 left white centered" >
      <//content
 </div>

 <div class="large-1 medium-1 small-1 left white centered" >
      //content
 </div>
 <div class="large-1 medium-1 small-1 left white centered" >
      //content
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Foundation 6 has built in Flex grid that makes it very easy to create any structure, for Foundation 5 you can add CSS to make it happen.

```
<div class="flex-row">
    <div class="columns">
        //Content
    </div>
    <div class="columns">
        //Content
    </div>
    <div class="columns">
        //content
    </div>
    <div class="columns">
        //content
    </div>
    <div class="columns">
        //content
    </div>
    <div class="columns">
        //content
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.flex-row{
    max-width: 75rem;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.flex-row .columns{
   -webkit-flex: 1 1 0px;
    -ms-flex: 1 1 0px;
    flex: 1 1 0px;
    padding-left: 0.625rem;
    padding-right: 0.625rem;
    min-width: 0;
}
```

See example http://codepen.io/shoaibik/pen/dXWYLO